# Is there a way to bypass this token while using jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, load

I recorded the script and it runs into error due to this token.When we login using the username and password, new token is generated for each login.Any way to bypass this?I wanted to perform a load test on a webpage that can be accessed only after user logs in. P.S I am just a beginner.

I wanted to bypass this token

Answer (score 0):

Your server requires token, so you can't do anything without it.

However, you can create a test plan without login request by:

1. Logging in manually and put the token into CSV file.
2. After that, using `CSV config` to read the CSV file
3. Remember to substitute the token by variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system is built as follows:

1. When you login using credentials the system replies with a token
2. The next requests assume that you supply the valid token otherwise they will fail

Ideally you should extract the token using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and then substitute the recorded hard-coded token with the variable from the Post-Processor.

The process is known as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and there is a lot of information on it in the Internet, for example [JMeter Regular Expression Extractor: How to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-regular-expressions-extractor)